# How to ignore "System.Net.Http.CurlException: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates" on non-Windows platforms?

Tags: https, .net-core

I have deployed a Kubernetes cluster in Microsoft Azure and would like to call some of the REST APIs from a .Net Core c# program using https. The certificates used when deploying the cluster not in a trusted CA. When I run this program on a Mac, I get the following error: "System.Net.Http.CurlException: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates"

On Windows I'm able to set a custom ServerCertificateValidationCallback in order to ignore the error:

```
    WinHttpHandler winHttpHandler = new WinHttpHandler();
    winHttpHandler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertificate;

public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
    HttpRequestMessage request,
    X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain,
    SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```

But, this is not supported under .Net Core on non-Windows platforms.

How can I ignore the error on other platforms?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with .NET Core.  We have been doing this with both 1.1, 2.0, and 2.1.

This can be done by constructing an `HttpHandler` and passing it into the `HttpClient` constructor.  The `HttpHandler` has a `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback`, which you can override to perform custom certificate validation.

Sample:

```
private HttpClient SampleBuildHttpClient()
{
    return new HttpClient(
        new HttpClientHandler
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = MyCallback,
        }); 
}

private bool MyCallback(HttpRequestMessage reqMsg, X509Certificate2 cert, X509Chain certChain, SslPolicyErrors policyErrors)
{
    //custom validation
    return true;
}
```

Comment: hi I was getting exactly the same error but when I tried your solution in .net2.0 it gave me different error. "The handler does not support custom handling of certificates with this combination of libcurl (7.51.0) and its SSL backend ("NSS/3.28.4")." any idea? I am using httpclient in aws lambda